# Django function calls

Tags: python, django

I am eventually going to setup a server using python 3.4 and django 1.8 on Windows. I have created several python programs that I want this server to run, but I am finding little on how to call these functions properly.

Is my only option to import these functions, then call them directly in a view?

```
from filename import myFunc

def myView(request):
    value = myFunc()
    # more processing
```

Comment: What, you serve an exe file to your users which you expect them to run? Seriously?

Comment: Why make us guess? **Show some code**. Describe your goals better. What version of Django are you even using?

Comment: In any case, I have no idea what you mean here. What distinction are you making between "importing" and "running" functions? You always need to import something in order to run it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I should have made the distinction between importing functions and running a file more properly. I made an edit that hopefully makes more sense.

Comment: Your question seems to imply some serious misunderstandings of how Django works, and maybe some about the process model in general. Are you suggesting that you want something that automatically differentiates between certain requests that are going to be handled by Django while routing others to a script? You probably cannot do this from within Django, if you can pull it off at all (given your `.py` files would be pretty specialized to handle an incoming web request).

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Is this more reasonable?

Comment: Importing them then calling in your view could be a reasonable approach.

Comment: I think I understand better what you want to do now, and yes it is probably fine. You may have to make copies of the scripts and move them inside your Django project, and you may want to restructure everything to make sense as a Django project, but of course there is really no problem with importing them and calling self-contained functions in a view. I don't think Python is going to let you name a variable `return`, though.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Will this function run on the back-end of my server? I don't want this code to be visible.

Comment: The only thing a view is going to output on the web is whatever you stick in your template/`HttpResponse`. None of your view code will be visible to the public unless your server is somehow compromised.